# Visual Studio Online Oauth how to generate authorization code

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, azure-devops

I am trying to authorize an app to use the Visual Studio Online REST APIs. but I keep getting back an error 400 page. The app is currently running in an Android Emulator, and authorization takes place inside a webview in the app.  My Authorization request looks something like this:

```
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize
?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&status=User&response_type=Assertion&scopes=vso.chat_write
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com
```

Now, I think that there is simply something I am missing on how Oauth works.  My redirect_uri points to a static HTML page, but when reading this:

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/get-started-auth-oauth2-vsi

It seems like my redirect URI is actually responsible for generating the authorization code. Unfortunately, the documentation does not explain what sort of programming I need to put in that URL to generate the code. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Your `redirect_uri` is not responsible for generating the `code`. The Authorization Server where you send the Authorization Request to will generate a `code` once the user authenticates and gives consent to do so. That `code` will be sent back as a query parameter to your `redirect_uri`. Your handling code there should pick up the `code` from the query parameters and exchange it for an access token at the Token Endpoint of the Authorization Server as in:

```
POST https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token
    ?client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
    &client_assertion={AppSecret}
    &grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
    &assertion={authorization code}
    &redirect_uri={callbackUrl}
```

Comment: But what if I am authorizing a mobile app? Do I still need to set up an external website to recieve the code? Does my site need to be set up in some special way to recieve that code? For example, since apparently the code is sent to the redirect_uri in an  HTTP request, does my URL need to have some kind of script to process that query string and then forward it back to the mobile device that actually requested the authorization?

Comment: A local webserver is one option and you'd have to handle some integration similar to what you suggest, a specialized port within your app that handles the HTTP redirect is another, but most often a custom URL scheme is registered for the mobile app and the redirect URI would look something like "myapp://callback"

Answer (score 0):

You can register the console app with the OS. Then you can use the app in the redirect URL. It requires Visual Studio's MFA and TLS. This is explained in [Visual Studio Online Oauth how to generate authorization code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017230/visual-studio-online-oauth-how-to-generate-authorization-code)

```
string RedirectUri = "app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97";
```